# Error initializing map

Tags: apex, soql

In my custom object I have two fields Name__c and QuestionString__c

I am trying to initialise a map with Name__c as key and QuestionString__c as value from a SOQL.

```
Map<String, String> ppmap = new Map<String, String>([SELECT Name__c, QuestionString__c FROM PObj__c]);
```

I tried the above but I get the error as

> Invalid initializer type List found for Map: expected a Map with the same key and value types, or a valid SObject List

Can someone tell me if it is possible to initialize a map directly (without "Id") from SOQL ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only use an initializer for a `Map<Id, SObject>`. If you want to map one field to another, you need a `for` loop.

Valid:

```
Map<Id, SObject> data = new Map<Id, SObject>([
    SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...
]);
```

Not Valid:

```
Map<String, String> data = new Map<String, String>([
    SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...
]);
```

Looping:

```
Map<String, String> data = new Map<String, String>();
for (MyObject__c record : [SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...])
{
    data.put(record.Field1__c, record.Field2__c);
}
```